# How should I automate variable creation from a string in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, flask, flask-restful

I am exploring ways to automate REST API resource and endpoint implementation using flask-restful. In flask-restful, the `add_resource(UpdateOrders, '/orders')` function links the endpoint to the resource in the framework. `UpdateOrders` is the endpoint, and also the name of a class containing logic for handling requests sent to `'/orders'`.

I could manually specify the endpoints and resources like this:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

# only Orders endpoint included for simplicity
class Orders(Resource):
    def get(self, item_id):
        return order_data[item_id]

def add_resources():
    api.add_resource(UpdateOrders, '/orders')
    api.add_resource(Orders, '/orders/<item_id>')
    api.add_resource(UpdatePayments, '/payments')
    api.add_resource(Payments, '/payments/<item_id>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    add_resources()
    app.run()
```

However, both the endpoints and resources will change depending on the use case of the REST API, e.g. instead of `'/orders'` I could have `'/appointments'`. I don't know what the use case will be (it is generated from the user's business process choreography).

My initial thought was to start by adding resources dynamically:

```py
def add_resources():

    # generate list of endpoint, resource tuples
    endpoint_resource = [('UpdateOrders', '/orders'), 
                         ('Orders', '/orders/<item_id>'),
                         ('UpdatePayments', '/payments'), 
                         ('Payments', '/payments/<item_id>')]

    for endpoint, resource in endpoint_resource:
        api.add_resource(endpoint, resource)
```

Of course, this won't work as `endpoint` here is a string, while `add_resource` requires a class. So my question is: can/should I convert `endpoint` from a string to a variable class name so that the API's resources can be created 'dynamically'?

In other words, instead of `endpoint` being assigned first to string `'UpdateOrders'`, it will be assigned to `<class '__main__.UpdateOrders'>`.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put your classes in the tuples? Class objects are still objects, so you should be able to manipulate them and pass them around in data structures pretty freely.